# measure from a linear functional (Riesz)

Tags: measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm reading [this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Riesz%27_representation_theorem) which states that, from a linear functional $\Lambda$, one can build a measure.

Setting: $X$ is a locally compact space.

Here are the steps. Let $\Lambda: C^0(X,R)\rightarrow R$ be a positive linear functional.

If $V$ is open in $X$ we define
$$
\mu(V)=\sup\{ \Lambda(f)\, where f\leq 1 and\, supp(f)\subset V  \}.
$$
If $E$ is not open, we define
$$
\mu(E)=\inf\{ \mu(V)\, where V\,\text{is open and } E\subset V \}.
$$

Now let $K$ be compact in $X$ and (from Urysohn's lemma), consider $g\in C^0(X,R)$ such that $0\leq g\leq 1$ and $g(K)=\{1\}$.

I want to prove that $\mu(K)\leq \Lambda (g)$.

The wikibook says that this is true «by definition».

If $V$ is any open containing $K$, I can prove that $\mu(V)\geq \Lambda(g)$ and $\mu(K)\leq \mu(V)$.

The wikibook also plays with a intermediate open set $V_{\alpha}=\{x : f(x)>\alpha\}$ but I'm not sure how it helps ? Maybe with a limit $\alpha\rightarrow 1$ ? But there are no continuity for $\Lambda$.

EDIT: closely related to [Rudin's Proof on Riesz Representation Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001940/rudins-proof-on-riesz-representation-theorem)

EDIT: answer in "Riesz-Markov Representation Theorem" (Kumaresan) [here](https://4dspace.mtts.org.in/expository-article-download.php?ai=160)

EDIT: two more references for a full proof:

- Theorem  THOooTWZWooHqGDAx in [giulietta](https://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/giulietta.pdf) (disclaimer: I'm the author)
- [The Riesz Markov Kakutani Representation Theorem](https://desvl.xyz/2020/09/19/The-Riesz-Markov-Kakutani-Representation-Theorem/)

Comment: Fix this ugly Latex lol.

Comment: A slight different approach is that of Daniell and later simplified and generalized by Stone. The integral thus obtained is the Daniell-Stone integral. It turns out to be equivalent to the measure you obtained though the procedures outlined in your OP. The first chapter of Rudin's RCA develops the integral the way you describe it.  Klauss Bichteler's book, Integration: a functional approach follows the Daniell approach.